# Stretching a cell in an embedded tablix to match a sub-report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is there a way to stretch an embedded tablix to match another cell on the same row?

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish and the result I'm getting.  Take note that this is a section of a bigger report and that the report is a form that is to be filled on paper.

**Wanted result mockup:**
[image]

**Current result:**

[image]

The current structure is this:

In the main tablix, I have 2 cells for headers, then 2 cells underneath.

In the left cell, I've put a tablix with 2 rows and 1 column.  The 1st row contains the comment field coming from the dataset. That row has a minimum height to allow By bottom row contains the static text to define the signature block.

In the right cell, there is a sub-report containing a list of statuses coming from a reference table.  That list is dynamic and can be modified at any time.  The typical list is 5 to 10 elements.

My goal is to stretch the first row of the left tablix so that the signature section is always at the bottom of that block.

Is there any way to accomplish that?  Or is there another way to accomplish the same thing that I do not think about?